# How to concat date and time column into one and then convert it into EST format?

Tags: hive, hiveql

If I have a df like the one shown below

```sql
SELECT `case_id` AS ID,`updt_dt` AS Update_date,`updt_tm` AS Update_time 
FROM case_dly_snap 
LIMIT 2"
```

My df comes like below:

[image]

where `update_date` is in date format and `update_time` is in string format.

How can I convert it into one in a date+time format?

Expected output

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this approach.

With Hive `Built-in Functions` format `update_time` and concat `update_date` to convert it into a `timestamp`.

As an example

```scala
val lstData = List((1,"2018-05-14","012230.627"),(2,"2018-05-15","070026.886"),(3,"2018-05-16","023525.669"))
val cols = Array("ID","update_date","update_time")
val dfTime = sc.parallelize(lstData).toDF(cols: _*)

dfTime.show()

dfTime.createOrReplaceTempView("df_time")

spark.sql(
"""SELECT ID, update_date, update_time,
  |to_utc_timestamp(concat_ws(' ',CAST(update_date AS STRING),concat_ws(':',substr(split(update_time,'\\.')[0],0,2),substr(split(update_time,'\\.')[0],3,2),substr(split(update_time,'\\.')[0],5,2))),'GMT') AS tms
  |FROM df_time """.stripMargin)
.show()
```

```scala
+---+-----------+-----------+-------------------+
| ID|update_date|update_time|                tms|
+---+-----------+-----------+-------------------+
|  1| 2018-05-14| 012230.627|2018-05-14 01:22:30|
|  2| 2018-05-15| 070026.886|2018-05-15 07:00:26|
|  3| 2018-05-16| 023525.669|2018-05-16 02:35:25|
+---+-----------+-----------+-------------------+
```

Comment: I am getting this error: Syntax or semantic analysis error thrown in server while executing query. Error message from server: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10016]: Line 1:93 Argument type mismatch 'updt_dt': Argument 2 of function CONCAT_WS must be "string or array<string>", but "date" was found.

Comment: Hi @Piccinin1992, in my example, the field `update_date` is a `string`, so you should cast `update_date` to string: `CAST(update_date AS STRING)` and it should work as expected. I updated the answer.